# How can I search for a value in an array and delete just one of those values if 2 or more is found?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array

```
var aos = ["a","a","a","b","b","c","d","d"];
```

I want to know if I can remove just 1 item if it finds 2 or more of the same value in the array. So for instance if it finds

`"a", "a"`

it will remove one of those "a"

This is my current code:

```
var intDennis = 1;
                        for (var i = 0; i < aos.length; i++) {
                            while (aos[i] == aos[intDennis]) {
                                aos.splice(i, 1);
                                intDennis++;
                                console.log(aos[intDennis], aos[i]);
                            } 
                            intDennis = 1;
                        }
```

NOTE: My array is sorted.

Comment: I appreciate all the answers, but It seems some are off track, I need some help with only deleting one value of a duplicated value, NOT all the duplicates values, so if I have 3 "a"'s I only want to delete ONE of those "a"'s.

I may need to find a different approach rather then deleting duplicates, any suggestions would be awesome.

Comment: do you need to delete one value ONLY if it has duplicates?

Comment: I have updated my answer below for your clarification of need.

Comment: I have posted an answer for this problem below -- one issue with the approach posted above is that `splice` *mutates* the array and thus the offsets used (e.g. `intDennis`) become wrong in relation to the data (also I suspect the probe should be `intDennis + i`). If the mutation approach is desired, consider *iterating/working backwards* which will remove the index offset issue (not that I am guaranteeing it is the only issue ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited after better understanding of OP use-case.
Updated solution and fiddle test to incorporate suggestion from pst in comments.

*(Not for nothing, but this method does not require the original array be sorted.)*

Try this...

```
var elements = [];
var temp = {};
for (i=0; i<aos.length; i++) {
    temp[aos[i]] = (temp[aos[i]] || 0) + 1;
}
for (var x in temp) {
    elements.push(x);
    for (i=0; i<temp[x]-2; i++) {
        elements.push(x);
    }
}
```

[Fiddle Test](http://jsfiddle.net/Md4mB/1/)

Comment: +1 (Because this is similar to the last stage of a bucket sort ;-) However, consider simplification of the initial temp-builder: `(x || 0) + 1` -> `1`, where `x` is a false-y value, including `undefined` and `0`.

Comment: Excellent - I had no idea how to do that in js - easy in ruby, where I live. ;) tks

Comment: You saved me such a headache and a half! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because you said you have a sorted array, you only need to remove the second time a element is found. You only need one *for*.
The `splice()` function returns the removed element so, just use it to not remove more elements of that kind.

This solution is more **clean** and **efficient**.

```
var aos = ["a","a","a","b","b","c","d","d"];
var lastRemoved = "";
for (var i = 1; i < aos.length; i++) {
    if (aos[(i-1)] == aos[i] && lastRemoved != aos[i]) {
         lastRemoved = aos.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

**Code tested and working**. Result: ["a", "a", "b", "c", "d"]

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER TO REMOVE ONLY 1 DUPLICATE:**

Assuming that each object will resolve to a unique String, here's a potential solution.  The first time the object is detected, it sets a counter for that object to one.  If it finds that object again, it splices that element out and increments the associated counter.  If it finds that element more times, it will leave it alone.

```
var elements = {};
for (var i = 0; i < aos.length; i++) {
    if(elements[aos[i]]){
        if(elements[aos[i]] == 1){
            aos.splice(i,1);//splice the element out of the array
            i--;//Decrement the counter to account for the reduced array
            elements[aos[i]]++;//Increment the count for the object
        }
    } else {
        elements[aos[i]] = 1;//Initialize the count for this object to 1;
    }
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rv7xG/2/)'s the test fiddle for this.

Comment: This doesn't work, as objects only have strings as property values, so, e.g., `[1, "1"]` would get reduced to `[1]`. Equally, `["toString"]` would become `[]`.

Comment: @gsnedders Yes, this will only work if the values resolve to unique strings.  In his example, he only has strings, so this solution should work.

Comment: @Dennis Martinez Answer now updated to only remove one duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

**REVISED EXAMPLE**

```
function removeDuplicate(arr) {
    var i = 1;
    while(i < arr.length) {
        if(arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
        while(arr[i] == arr[i - 1] && i < arr.length) {
            i += 1;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    return arr;
}
alert(removeDuplicate(["a","a","a","b","b","c","d","d"]));
```

Comment: This will remove all duplicates, not just one. http://jsfiddle.net/XKsWy/ -- the result is `["a","b","c","d"]` when it should be `["a","a","b","c","d"]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any better way to do this on an unsorted array than an approach with O(n^2) behaviour. Given ES5 array-builtins (supported in all modern browsers, though not in IE prior to IE9), the following works:

`aos.filter(function(value, index, obj) { return obj.indexOf(value) === index; })`

Answer (score 0):

I would not mutate the input -- that is, don't use `splice`. This will simplify the problem a good deal. Using a new array object here may actually be *more efficient*. This approach utilizes the fact that the input array is sorted.

Consider: ([jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fC2xq/7/))

```
var input = ["a","a","a","b","b","c","d","d"]
var result = []

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var elm = input[i]
    if (input[i+1] === elm) {
        // skip first element (we know next is dup.)
        var j = i + 1
        for (; input[j] === elm && j < input.length; j++) {    
            result.push(input[j])
        }
        i = j - 1
    } else {
        result.push(elm)
    }
}

alert(result) // a,a,b,c,d
```

Happy coding.

---

Replace `===` with a custom equality, as desired. Note that it is the first item is omitted from the output, which may not always be "correct".